# Difference between isometry and euclidean motion

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I know that they both preserve distance however what is the difference between them?

I think isometry is part of Linear Transformations and euclidean motion is not

Comment: The terms are generally used synonymously

Comment: One man said that Euclidian Motion is a bigger set than isometry that's what makes me doubt

Comment: Depending on context and the specific definitions being used the precise meaning may vary, but without that context I cannot say exactly whether or not some difference in meaning is being implied. It would help if you could add a specific text where these words are being used and you are unsure of their meaning to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me restrict attention to the Euclidean plane $\mathbb E^2$ (similar considerations play out in higher dimensions, although enumerating the Euclidean motions in those cases is more laborious).

The Euclidean motions of $\mathbb E^2$, by definition, consist of: the translations, rotations, reflections, and glide reflections, and the identity map. In the study of Euclidean geometry one often starts with just the reflections, but then one proves that the motions that you get by composing finitely many reflections consist precisely of the translations, rotations, reflections, glide reflections, and the identity. In more detail: the composition of an even number of reflections is always a translation, rotation, or the identity map; and the composition of an odd number of reflections is always a reflection or glide reflection.

The isometries of the plane, by definition, are all functions $f : \mathbb E^2 \to \mathbb E^2$ that preserve distance, meaning that $d(f(p),f(q))=d(p,q)$ for all $p,q \in \mathbb E^2$.

Now there's a theorem to prove:

> In $\mathbb E^2$, every Euclidean motion is an isometry and every isometry is a Euclidean motion.

The hardest part of the proof is the following key step, which is kind of the last step in proving that every isometry is a Euclidean motion:

> If an isometry fixes the three vertices of some triangle then that isometry is the identity map.

Comment: in the context of linear transformations isometry would be a subset of euclidean motion because euclidean motion would include translations?

Comment: Not all linear transformations are isometries, and not all isometries are linear transformations. For example, a linear transformation *must* fix the origin of the coordinate system, whereas an isometry does not have that requirement. Furthermore, the only linear transformations which *are* isometries are the orthogonal matrices, i.e. those matrices which are diagonalizable and have eigenvalues $\pm 1$; and each of those is either a rotation or reflection fixing the origin, or the identity. No translation fixes the origin.

Comment: I should emphasize that the theory of Euclidean motions, and the theory of isometries, can in some sense be done in an entirely "coordinate free" manner, consistent with the original approach of Euclid in which coordinates do not appear. Of course, since Descartes, coordinate geometry has vastly increased our understanding of many aspects of geometry, including ordinary Euclidean planar geometry.